# Ansible: add items to single string conditionally

Tags: postgresql, ansible

Currently working on ansible playbook for postgresql installation.

Trying to insert multiple values to `shared_preload_libraries`. Idea is to be able to insert them conditionnaly and different roles must be able to append to this line without overwriting it.

Current solution:

```
- name: Check whether postgresql.conf contains "pg_stat_statements"
  command: grep "pg_stat_statements" "{{ pg_data }}/postgresql.conf"
  register: check_shared_libs
  check_mode: no
  ignore_errors: yes
  changed_when: no

- name: Modify postgresql.conf add pg_stat_statements shared library.
  replace:
      backup: yes
      dest: "{{ pg_data }}/postgresql.conf"
      regexp: "^#?(shared_preload_libraries = '.*)(')"
      replace: '\1,pg_stat_statements\2'
  when: check_shared_libs.rc != 0
  notify: restart postgres
```

which gives me something like this: `shared_preload_libraries = ',pg_stat_statements,powa,pg_stat_kcache,pg_qualstats,pg_wait_sampling'`

Works fine, but I wonder if there's any better way to do it.

Comment: You're really close to a great question - the last thing is to address your last line. If your code works, we need to know _why_ you want to make it better. What technical limitation are you facing that is forcing you to refactor this?

Comment: Dont like using command module - not so "ansible" for me.

Answer (score 1):

one way to avoid using the `command` task is the below. it comprises of 2 tasks because reading a **remote** file into a variable cant be done with a lookup plugin..

so, step1 we read the whole file into a variable and step2 we check if the variable contains the `pg_stat_statements`:

code:

```
---
- name: test play
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  become: yes
  vars:
    pg_stat_statements_exists: false

  tasks:
  - name: read file
    slurp:
      src: /tmp/postgresql.conf
    register: postgresql_file

  - name: check pg_stat_statements exists
    set_fact:
      pg_stat_statements_exists: true
    when: postgresql_file['content'] | b64decode is search('pg_stat_statements') == true

  - name: print variable that will control the replace task that follows
    debug:
      var: pg_stat_statements_exists
```

and adding your `replace` task with the modified `when` condition:

```
- name: Modify postgresql.conf add pg_stat_statements shared library.
  replace:
      backup: yes
      dest: "{{ pg_data }}/postgresql.conf"
      regexp: "^#?(shared_preload_libraries = '.*)(')"
      replace: '\1,pg_stat_statements\2'
  when: pg_stat_statements_exists == true
  notify: restart postgres
```

hope it helps